# Why does the container created with - 'docker run -d alpine sleep infinity' goes into exited/stopped state?

Tags: docker

I have nothing to execute inside a container but want it to be running. So, I tried to create a container using the following command line - `'docker run -d alpine sleep infinity'`. But, instead, it is going into a exited/stopped state immediately. What's the explanation?

Comment: Just use  sleep 999999999d where d indicates days.

Comment: As of alpine 3.15.0, alpine sleep seems to support infinity now.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

`alpine` is busybox-based, and doesn't provide the full array of options and extensions available in GNU tools; `infinity` as an option to sleep is an example of something that's unavailable.

Consider instead:

```
docker run -d alpine sh -c 'while sleep 3600; do :; done'
```

Comment: I should have seen 'docker logs <container id>'. It says - "sleep: invalid number 'infinity'".

Answer (score 8):

Changing the entrypoint in the Dockerfile with this did the trick for me

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/sh","-c","sleep infinity"]
```

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Instead, vote up the answers that you find helpful. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/31250367)

Comment: i don't understand your comment @Blastfurnace

Answer (score -1):

in Docker-compose or dockerfile you can use
command: ["/bin/ash", "-c", "sleep infinity"]
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/ash", "-c", "sleep infinity"]

seems like alpine uses ash as a shell