# How to install "sleep" command for "scratch" docker image

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I tried this Dockerfile

```
FROM alpine AS build
FROM scratch
COPY --from=build /bin/sleep .
CMD ["sleep", "infinity"]
```

Build is passing, but after running the image I'm getting this error message:

> docker: Error response from daemon: failed to create task for container: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: exec: "sleep": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown.

Edit: This question is close related to software development and docker deployment.
Explanation: If application process, which is running into container, isn't designed to run in the foreground, container should be prevented from exiting after startup. That's why `sleep` or `CMD ["tail", "-f", "/dev/null"]` is used.

Comment: The Alpine `sleep` is a link to the `busybox` executable. And that depends on a dynamic library, that you don't copy.

Comment: I suspect the BusyBox in the `busybox` image is a static binary.  But it's also pretty much the only thing in the `busybox` image, and I'd just use that image instead of copying it into `scratch`.

Comment: Additionally, `infinity` is a GNU extension. At least older versions of busybox sleep didn't support it -- see [Why does the container created with - 'docker run -d alpine sleep infinity' goes into exited/stopped state?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39729598/14122)

Comment: BTW, I don't agree that "docker deployment" is inherently a software development topic; it's something ops people deal with just as much as developers do, and our scope is limited to questions "**unique to**" software development. As such, I don't see how the recently-edited in paragraph constitutes a valid argument for reopening; you're _stating a conclusion_ that it's on-topic, but not making anything I can recognize as an argument to support that conclusion. (Granted, if it were my choice I'd kick at least half the other docker-tagged questions out to [unix.se] as well)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Hans Kilian said, Alpine's `sleep` is a link to [`busybox`](https://www.busybox.net/about.html), which in turn has dynamic libraries.

This Dockerfile will copy the necessary files and use the correct entrypoint to use sleep:

```
FROM alpine as build
FROM scratch
COPY --from=build /lib/ld-musl-x86_64.so.1 /lib/ld-musl-x86_64.so.1
COPY --from=build /bin/busybox /bin/busybox
CMD ["/bin/busybox", "sleep", "5"]
```

Try it with `docker build -t sleeper .` and then `docker run --rm -it sleeper`.